# How to get mist only at horizon line?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, effects

Ok I am trying to create something like this - where there is a "layer" of mist that occurs only at the horizon line -

[image]

I have glowing objects in my scene that create a glare and Ive followed tutorials to get mist, however it covers the ENTIRE background, not just a line in the center.

[image]

What can I do to get the horizon only mist?

Comment: Use a [mask](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/matte/box_mask.html) to limit where the mist pass is combined.

Comment: you could put a plane and play with its transparency

Comment: @moonboots what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @sambler sorry, not great with nodes, do you have an example of exactly where to put it - I connected it where the mist comes out of render layers, and this works, but I need some kind of blur to make it not as sharp - where would I do that?

Comment: @skyguy add a [box mask node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/matte/box_mask.html) and connect it to the fac of your alpha over. Add a distort->Rotate if you need to adjust the angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skyguy, here is what I meant:

- Create a plane, give it an *Image Texture* and paint it in black and white.
- Change the node organization: Plug the *Image Texture* you've created into the *factor* of a *Mix* shader so that it separates a *Diffuse* (or *Emission*) node (probably white) from a *Transparent* node (make sure that this Transparent is 100% white which doesn't seem to be the case by default). Add a second *Mix* shader to give transparency to your diffuse, plug it into the *Output*.
- Now you have a plane which creates a mist. It's a much lighter solution than Mist or Volume Scatter (well, I guess...). It won't fit everytime though, as it's a fake 2D mist. But for example if you want your camera to rotate around the scene you can paint on a semi-circular or semi-spherical surface instead of a plane, etc.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. thank you so much, seriously. Tangent but is there an easy way to have this billboard - so it always faces the camera?

Comment: as I said it's a fake mist, so you have to find tricks, for example if you want your camera to rotate you can paint on a semi-circular surface instead of a plane, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar issue. I wanted a nice fall off in the distance for a jet scene flying over water. What I did was to use the mist pass, set the start so it was just beyond the jet, then the depth finished just before the edge of the ocean plane. Then I cranked up the strength in the compositor using a map value. It didn't hide the join between the ocean and the sky completely but it helped a lot, specially with DOF on the jet.