# How do I create mist easily?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want to make mist easily. Can someone teach me? I use a MAC and I use Blender 2.79b, making a MineCraft scene. Oh, I'm also a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Zackarus, there are at least 3 methods to create mist: 1 - Cube with Volume Scatter material, 2 - Mist in Compositing, 3 - Fake 3D mist with a plane.

The first method, Volume Scatter, is the most basic, but it's a little bit heavy if you have a slow computer :

- Create a cube that contains your scene + camera.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Display* > *Maximum Draw Type* > choose *Wire* so that your cube is transparent in *Solid* display.
- Give your cube a material with a *Volume Scatter* node plugged into the *Volume* socket of the *Material Output* node. Keep the *Density* value low so that the mist is not too heavy (here: 0.04).

[image]

Second method, with the Compositing, tuto here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxNeMMZs_sM

Third method, fake 3D mist with a plane, answer here: [How to get mist only at horizon line?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116904/how-to-get-mist-only-at-horizon-line/117001)